# Complex line integral of $\frac{e^z}z$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, line-integrals, cauchy-integral-formula

I have an integral
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z}\,\mathrm dz.$$
I defined $g: [0,2\pi]$, $g(t)=e^{it}$.
The integral then becomes. 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{e^{it}}\mathrm dt.$$
I used the property that states that the value of a function at the center of a closed circle is the same as the mean value of that same function at the circumference (comes from Cauchy's integral formula).

My answer was $i2\pi$. The book comes with no answers. Is it correct?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct, but you don't need to convert your integral to $\int_0^{2\pi}ie^{e^{it}}\,\mathrm dt$ (note that you missed the first $i$). Just apply directly Cauchy's integral formula:$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{\lvert z\rvert=1}\frac{e^z}z\,\mathrm dz=e^0=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

You're right, but why not Cauchy's Integral Formula?

$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{z}\,\mathrm dz$$

$$ = \oint_{|z|=1}\frac{e^z}{(z-w)^{n+1}}\,\mathrm dz$$

$$ = 2 \pi i \frac{1}{n!}f^{n}(w) = 2 \pi i$$

where $n=0,w=0 \in int(\{|z|=1\})$ and $f(z)=e^z$, which is holomorphic in $int(\{|z|=1\})$ because $f: \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is entire.

Comment: This is a novel idea, $0∈\{|z|=1\}$, I think you mean $0∈\{|z|<1\}$ in the first case and $\{|z|<1+\varepsilon\}$ in the second case (as you need the curve to be inside the open domain where the function is holomorphic).

Comment: @LutzL I forgot $int$! Thank you!

Comment: That is even more interesting as the curve as a one-dimensional path does not have interior points. And you need the function holomorphic on the curve, thus in some neighborhood of the curve.

Comment: @LutzL What's the word for region bounded by the path in Jordan curve theorem?

Comment: The notation $\text{int}(A)$ is IMO usually used for the set of inner/interior points of $A$, the maximal open set inside $A$. For other uses one should add some words.

Comment: @LutzL Ok so what should I say?

Comment: Per http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html, "the curve $\{|z|=1\}$ encloses $w=0$". https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2032882/115115 has "$w=0$ is an interior point of the curve $\{|z|=1\}$." Use your sources for formulations of the CIF to get other possibilities. At the moment it is not wrong, just ambiguous.